# "Questions" list is showing questions with same number of votes

Tags: bug, questions

Many a times when I keep refreshing pages to find questions I can answer, I see that, in some pages, all the questions have the same number of up votes! I don't think the questions have actually got the number of up votes as shown.

First time, I saw all the questions had 7 votes in a page. I thought that was just coincidence, But the same thing occurred twice or thrice again.

I think this is a bug? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Here's an example (This happened today) :

> [image: All the questions have 2 votes]

Comment: Has its happened "many a times", or just "twice or thrice" plus one? Out of how many page views in total? Are you sorting by number of votes? Is there anything to suggest it's not a consequence of sorting by number of votes, not coincidence, and not selective memory?

Comment: It has happened 4 times now. I just started using StackOverflow last week even though I registered months ago. So maybe in future, it'll occur many times... And no, not sorting by number of votes. Sorting by 'No answers'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OP mentions in comments that they sort by 'No Answers']

Sorting by 'No Answers' sub-sorts the list by 'Number of upvotes'.

Therefore the behaviour you observe is inevitable.

Comment: That must be the case! Thanks for correcting me. :)